# Execute the script from my Chrome extension on newly created iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension which transform `spotify:` URI into clickable links. The code is OK (parsing, replacing, etc.) and everything is working fine on "classic" websites.

But, when using web-client Hangouts (hangouts.google.com), every chat window is a new iframe created on the fly, and the script doesn't seem to be executed.

As I read, executing scripts inside iframes is not the easiest thing to do. Thanks to another post on SO, I achieved to load my JS files to the iframes but the code is still not executed…

---

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Spotilink",
    "description": "Transforms Spotify's URI into a clickable link",
    "version": "0.1",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["findAndReplaceDOMText.js", "spotilink.js", "script.js"],
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ],

    "permission": [
        "active_tabs"
    ],

    "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"]
}
```

**script.js (probably ugly code, MVP purpose)**

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
var t = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('findAndReplaceDOMText.js');
t.src = chrome.extension.getURL('spotilink.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
t.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(t);
```

**spotilink.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", findAndReplaceDOMText(document.documentElement, {
    find: /[A-Za-z0-9]*/gi,
    replace: function(portion, match) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.className = 'spotilink';
        a.setAttribute('href', match);
        a.textContent = portion.text;
        return a;
    }
}));
```

**findAndReplaceDOMText.js**

Just a library to parse a DOM and replace matched elements.

---

To summarize: parsing and replacing is fine (`spotilink.js` and `findAndReplaceDOMText.js` does the job perfectly), but having the same results in iframes created on-the-fly is not the same piece of cake.

Any idea on where I missed something?

Comment: Hangout most probably creates iframes with src equal to about:blank so you need "match_about_blank":true in manifest for the content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm nope, doesn't work better :-/

Comment: Well, debug it in devtools. Things of concern: 1) description value in manifest has invalid double doublequote, 2) the code you run in the page context is not wrapped in IIFE.